# Populating an array of a child class using a parents method

Tags: php

I have created a Programmer class with two methods:

public method getLanguage() - which returns all languages, as an array, that the programmer knows.

public method addLanguage() - which adds a new language to the list of languages.

```
class Programmer 
{
    private $languages = [];

    public function getLanguages()
    {
        return $this->languages;
    }

    public function addLanguage($language)
    {
        $this->languages[] = $language;
    }
}
```

I have also created another ProgrammerTeacher class, which extends Programmer and has one additional public method:

public method teach(Programmer $programmer, $language) - which teaches Programmer a language if ProgrammerTeacher knows the required language.

```
class ProgrammerTeacher extends Programmer
{
    private $languages = [];

    public function teach(Programmer $programmer, $language)
    {
        if(in_array($language, $this->languages)) {
            $programmer->addLanguage($language);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

For example, the following code shows how ProgrammerTeacher teaches Programmer the new language ('PHP'):

```
$teacher = new ProgrammerTeacher();
$teacher->addLanguage('PHP');
$programmer = new Programmer();
$teacher->teach($programmer, 'PHP');
print_r($programmer->getLanguages());

// result print is: Array ()
```

The array is empty because this conditional resolves to false:

```
in_array($language, $this->languages)
```

Which is strange because when I call:

```
$teacher->getLanguages()
// result is Array ( [0] => PHP )
```

I think I'm not userstanding simple inheritence properly. Could somebody please take the time to explain what is going on here?

Comment: Change `private $languages` to `protected $languages` in `Programmer` and remove it from `ProgrammerTeacher`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to your $languages attributes by using your public function getLanguages() because the keyword public means that everybody can acces to it.

But you can't acces directly to the attribute languages because it's a private attribute of the parent class. So you shouldn't redeclare the attribute $languages in the child class and change the private keyword in "protected" so the class ProgrammerTeacher can acces to it.

Or you can can simply use the method getLanguages() which is public.

If you replace the condition in_array($language, $this->languages) by this condition : in_array($language, $this->getLanguages()) you'll have the expected results.

Excuse my english that's not my natural language !